# MySQL join two columns on a single column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have 2 tables:

1. table_name: `user_tracking`
   With columns:  id, bill_no, container_type, origin_id, destination_id
2. table_name: `sea_ports`
   With columns: id, bill_no, port_name

I want to write a single query to get the origin port_name and the destination port_name.

my query is :

```
select a.container_type, 
       b.port_name as origin_port
from user_tracking a 
left join sea_ports b 
on a.bill_no = b.bill_no 
where a.bill_number = '$bill_no'
```

How do I join the two columns `origin_id` and `destination_id` on the same field `id` from the table `sea_ports` to get two different outputs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to join the table `sea_ports` twice so you can get the `port_name` for each origin and destination. And One more thing, *I guess*, you need need to use `INNER JOIN` rather than `LEFT JOIN` because there will always be destination and origin right? `:D`

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        a.bill_no,
        a.container_type,
        b.port_name AS Origin_name,
        c.port_name AS Destination_name
FROM    user_tracking a
        INNER JOIN sea_ports b
            ON a.origin_id = b.id
        INNER JOIN sea_ports c
            ON a.destination_id = c.id
WHERE   a.bill_number = '$bill_no'
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*) came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @JW.. ohh great...it worked.thanks a lot..i would surely go through the link .thanks a ton again.